# Facebook like button not created in iframe in firefox

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have a Facebook like button on a website, it links to their Facebook page.

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=158676140902498&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df3c3ba27b53005a%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F07bce2b0664e8df0ed388a0c7647cf80.sites.gozesty.com%252Ff4c48dfa4eebd4%26domain%3D07bce2b0664e8df0ed388a0c7647cf80.sites.gozesty.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMissionBrewery&node_type=link&width=450&layout=box_count&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&send=false&extended_social_context=false

If you copy and paste that into Chrome it works perfectly.
In Firefox and Safari no item shows up.

I tried making the like button in Firefox and realize when the link is a facebook link the item doesn't show. Anyone know why this would be and a possible solution?

Comment: How are you creating this on your page? Is it the XFBML or iFrame version? If you provide a code example, you're more likely to receive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my safari (6.0.2)

Comment: Solution: in order to see the like button you have to be logged into facebook, makes sense, thank you for the help